# Keras: How to use a generator with variable input sizes

Tags: python, numpy, keras, generator

I have a large dataset and heavy augmentions, thus I rely onthe `keras.utils.Sequence` generator and let Keras do the multiprocessing. So, using the simple `model.fit(...)` command is no option for me, when it comes to having a variable input size. Furthermore, due to my specific problem it is not a good idea to resize or pad the images.

Also chosing a batch-size of 1 is not very handy, because of BatchNormalization Layers.

I have variable image sizes, and created a toy example of my problem:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16 as model
from keras.utils import Sequence
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model

CLASSES = 10
class ExampleGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self,dataset_length=100,batch_size=8):
        self.dataset_length = dataset_length
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(self.dataset_length / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self,idx):

        # create random targets
        Y_batch = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(self.batch_size,CLASSES))
        X = []

        for i in range(self.batch_size):


            # create a random image with a random size

            width = np.random.randint(64,256)
            height = np.random.randint(64,256)
            img = np.random.rand(width,height,3)
            X.append(img)

        X_batch = np.array(X)
        return X_batch,Y_batch


gen = ExampleGenerator()
input_tensor = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))

base_model = model(input_tensor=input_tensor,weights=None, include_top=False)

output = base_model.output

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(output)
x = Dense(512)(x)
predictions = Dense(CLASSES)(x)


model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model.fit_generator(gen)
```

Note that this example is only for the purpose of recreating my problem.

The followng error message will be prompted if the script is executed:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 1)

which of course is due to the numpy arry returned by `__getitem__` with only the batch_size as a fixed size.

When the list `X` is not convert to a numpy array different error occurs:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 8
>   arrays:

So, how can I have a variable input size with a keras generator?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a batch_size greater than 1 for variable size images. If you're using variable size images and you want to send in a batch size greater than one then you should fix the dimensions for the input of the model and add some padding to reach that fixed size in you generator.

Comment: do you have any source on that from keras? It is somewhat hard to believe that the framework is limited like that. Because with a batch of 1, Batchnorm layers would suffer, and the resizing or padding of the images would result in a corruption of the images

Comment: Since you're using GlobalAveragePooling2D() , you can use the inbuilt generator of keras with variable size images. But it resizes the image using some interpolation method more specifically "nearest" .  For using a custom generator you'll have to write something for resizing an image to do batch processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```py
X_batch = np.asarray(X)
```